# Migrate `DateTimeField` to `DateField` in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I got objects that have an attribute that is a `DateTimeField` now I want to change this to a `DateField`.

But I already have data in my database so just doing this migration:

```
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='assignedtip',
        name='date',
        field=models.DateField(),
    ),
```

will not work, as the table is broken afterwards.

How can I make sure, that when executing this migration with `makemigration` the `DateTimeField` values are first converted to `DateFields`?

Comment: What do you mean with "broken"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be better to do this in four steps:

1. first add a field `assignedtip_date` that contains `NULL` for a start;
2. then run a *data migration* that populates the field with the truncated part of the `assignedtip`;
3. then remove the `assginedtip` field; and
4. finally rename the `assginedtip_date` field to `assignedtip`.

The migration thus will look like:

```
# app_name/migrations/0123_some_name.py

from django.db import migrations, models
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate


def migrate_date(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model("app_name", "MyModel")
    MyModel.objects.update(assignedtip_date=TruncDate('assignedtip'))


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [("migrations", "0001_initial")]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            "MyModel", "assignedtip_date", models.DateField(null=True)
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_date),
        migrations.RemoveField("MyModel", "assignedtip"),
        migrations.RenameField("MyModel", "assignedtip_date", "assignedtip"),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I think u confused 'assginedtip' with 'date' as the field is named 'date'. I tried this but when running the specific migration, it says: `Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0012_alter_assignedtip_date, from tips
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Comment: Well likely it used to be an old migration that was already done, so it was injected in the `django_migrations` table. This thus also means that the data was likely corrupted by the previous time you tried to migrate?

Comment: Ahh I see. Yes, but I resetted it with another migration. So I can't just remove a migration. My bad.

Comment: I ran it now and my admin site is broken now, giving me `TypeError at /admin/tips/assignedtip/
fromisoformat: argument must be str` here `python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py, line 114, in parse_datetime
        return datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(value) `

Comment: Can you edit the question with the full traceback?

Comment: Yes, I dit that.

Comment: @progNewbie: ah, but so the migration already was done. Then in your model you need to change `assignedtip to a `DateField`.

Comment: Ohhh... of course. Thank you so much. It works <3